# Tracking nested transactions with Spring TransactionSynchronizationManager

Tags: spring, transactions

I am working with a module that uses Sprint transactions

After a transaction (T1) is committed, I want to take some action on the data handled by that specific transaction (T1) only. If T1 called a method (in the same thread) which started a new transaction T2, then I don't care if T2 committed. I want to take my action only if T1 commits

Spring's `TransactionSynchronizationManager` doesn't seem to address nested transactions (i.e. it calls commit callbacks right when any transaction running on that thread commits). That means if T2 commits, any `TransactionSynchronization`'s added by T1 will also get called

I considered using the name of the transaction that committed (`TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName())`, however that won't work if the same method initiates multiple transactions on the same thread (e.g. if we have a method that has `TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW` and it calls itself)
Note - in spring managed transactions, the default transaction name is the fully qualified class name followed by the method name

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the answer after reading through some Spring code (wish this was documented/blogged somewhere instead)

When Spring (`AbstractPlatformTransactionManager`) comes across a transactional method with `TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW`, it suspends the current transaction.

During suspension, it suspends and removes all existing `TransactionSynchronization` that were registered during the transaction (please refer to `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doSuspendSynchronization()`)

After the inner transaction is finished, it adds/registers all the suspended ones back to the `TransactionSynchronizationManager` (please refer to `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doResumeSynchronization()`)

This ensures that committing the inner transaction only invokes the synchronisation's that were added added by the inner transaction itself